# Access subclass of abstract class in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, abstract-class

If I have a HashMap field called map and I have one Enum called **Slot** and one abstract class called **Item** and want to access the **Item's** subclass called **Chair** that inherits from it how can I access it from within the abstract class? This is my field:

```
private HashMap<Slot, Item> map;
```

I want to somehow access it by doing:

```
Chair chair = map.get(Slot.CHAIR);
```

But that is not possible. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to cast the object? `Chair chair = (Chair) map.get(Slot.CHAIR);`

Comment: @GauthamM Thank you, add answer to question and I will accept it. I can't believe I forgot about casting!

Comment: Remember also that you'll get a ClassCastException at runtime if your slot doesn't contain a Chair.

Comment: Alright, so I should preferably implement a try/catch to handle that then @tgdavies ?

Comment: @MarcusC It would be better to close the question as it is kind of a "typo" error

Comment: Not if the way you manage your data structure guarantees that won't happen. If you make a mistake, you'll have a runtime error and have some debugging to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure, that the `Item` you are accessing is a `Chair` you can do a simple cast like this:

```java
Chair chair = (Chair) map.get(Slot.CHAIR);
```

If the `Item` you retrieve from the Map is not a `Chair`, this solution will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.